# Transforming several objects via OnGui in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new to Unity and Javascript and trying to recreate the puzzle game Cryptica as a learning experience to get into the engine. I am trying to move two objects simultaneously when calling one of four OnGUI buttons: left, up, right and down. The script has been attached to both objects but only moves one.

If I create an empty game object and add both objects into this and place the script on the empty object then both move, but I'm then not able to create logic to move each object differently depending on different scenarios (ie. if one object is at the end of the board it should no longer move in that direction but another object may still move). Here is the code, let me know if an image will be more helpful.

```
var cubeMovement = 11;

function Update () {

}

function OnGUI () {
    //Move dynamic cubes
    if (GUI.Button (Rect (250,150,50,50), "Up")) {
        transform.Translate(cubeMovement,0,0);
    }

    if (GUI.Button (Rect (350,250,50,50), "Right")) {
        transform.Translate(0,0,-cubeMovement);

    }

    if (GUI.Button (Rect (250,350,50,50), "Down")) {
        transform.Translate(-cubeMovement,0,0);
    }

    if (GUI.Button (Rect (150,250,50,50), "Left")) {
        transform.Translate(0,0,cubeMovement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using this script on 2 different objects is that both objects are rendering the same 4 buttons.  So you actually have 8 buttons on screen, it's just that the ones last drawn are on top.

The logic for updating multiple cubes would look something like this:

```
function CubeVisible(var go: GameObject){
    var screenPos : Vector3 = camera.WorldToScreenPoint (go.transform.position);
    if(screenPos.x < 0) return false;
    if(screenPos.x > Screen.width) return false;

    //Do the same for the y axis

    //Negative-z means the object is behind the camera.
    if(screenPos.z < 0) return false;
    return true;    //return true if the object wasn't outside any bounds.
}
function UpdateCubes(var dir: Vector3){
    var cubes: GameObject[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cubes"); 

    for (cube in cubes) { 
        var pos = cube.transform.position;
        var new_pos = pos + dir;

        if(CubeVisible(new_pos)==true)
            cube.transform.Translate(dir);
    } 
}

function OnGUI () {
    //Move dynamic cubes
    if (GUI.Button (Rect (250,150,50,50), "Up")) {
        UpdateCubes(Vector3(cubeMovement,0,0));
    }

    if (GUI.Button (Rect (350,250,50,50), "Right")) {
        UpdateCubes(Vector3(0,0,-cubeMovement));
    }

    if (GUI.Button (Rect (250,350,50,50), "Down")) {
        UpdateCubes(Vector3(-cubeMovement,0,0));
    }

    if (GUI.Button (Rect (150,250,50,50), "Left")) {
        UpdateCubes(Vector3(0,0,cubeMovement));
    }
}
```

My javascript-fu is a little rusty, I'm a C# guy so hopefully I haven't made a silly mistake.  Above should be what you're looking for.  The problem with testing if your objects are still in view is that your objects are in world coordinates and it sounds like you want to know if your object is offscreen. The easiest way to do that is to first convert your object's position to 2D screen coordinates and then test if it's on screen.  That path too has issues, it assumes your object is centered around it's own origin.

Oh and 'tags.'  Tags can be found in the "Inspector" when selecting any game object.  You can create your own custom tags.  See the wiki for an explanation.